# Running until a certain value linked list

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I want to sum the nodes until 0 is reached and update the original linked list with the new values.

Note: it skips 0 until it reaches a number to calc sum or the end of the linked list.

Definition of node:

```
struct Node {
int data;
Node* next;
};

void updateLinkedList(Node* head)
{
Node* currentNode = head;

int temp = 0;
int sum = 0;


while (currentNode != NULL)
{
    temp = currentNode->data;

    while(temp != 0)
    {
        sum = sum + currentNode->data;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}
}
```

I'm attempting to do the next thing:

User input linked list:

```
1 2 0 5 3 0 4
```

Updated Linked List:

```
3 8 4
```

Comment: What if the list starts with 0 as for example  0 1 2 how will the updated list look?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It would skip 0 until it reaches a number or the end of the list if there are no numbers

Comment: Could you post the definition of `Node`, please?

Comment: @LHLaurini There, I added it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function can be implemented for example the following way

```
void updateLinkedList( Node * &head )
{
    for ( Node **current = &head; *current != nullptr; )
    {
        if ( ( *current )->data == 0 )
        {
            Node *tmp = *current;
            *current = ( *current )->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            while ( ( *current )->next != NULL && ( *current )->next->data != 0 )
            {
                ( *current )->data += ( *current )->next->data;
                Node *tmp = ( *current )->next;
                ( *current )->next = ( *current )->next->next;
                delete tmp;
            }

            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void clear( Node * &head )
{
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

void assign( Node * &head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    clear( head );

    for (Node **current = &head; n--; current = &( *current )->next)
    {
        *current = new Node{ *a++, nullptr };
    }
}

std::ostream &display( const Node * const &head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for (const Node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
    {
        os << current->data << " -> ";
    }

    return os << "null";
}

void updateLinkedList( Node * &head )
{
    for (Node **current = &head; *current != nullptr; )
    {
        if (( *current )->data == 0)
        {
            Node *tmp = *current;
            *current = ( *current )->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            while (( *current )->next != NULL && ( *current )->next->data != 0)
            {
                ( *current )->data += ( *current )->next->data;
                Node *tmp = ( *current )->next;
                ( *current )->next = ( *current )->next->next;
                delete tmp;
            }

            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = nullptr;

    const int a[] = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 5, 3, 0, 4 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    assign( head, a, N );

    display( head ) << '\n';

    updateLinkedList( head );

    display( head ) << '\n';

    clear( head );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0 -> 5 -> 3 -> 0 -> 4 -> null
3 -> 8 -> 4 -> null
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. Could you please explain to me what assign and clear are supposed to do? Thank you again :)

Comment: @Nitzan clear frees all allocated memory of the list. The list becomes empty. assign builds a list based on array elements.

Answer (score 2):

In modern C++ you rarely want to deal directly with memory allocation. You'll usually use classes from the standard library or another library. That's because it's easy to forget something and cause your entire program to crash or create [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

It's important to be familiar with memory allocation and to know how to implement a linked list manually. That's handled by Vlad's answer.

I wanted to add: in the future, you'll probably want to use higher level functionality. This is how I'd write your function if you were using [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list), one of the standard containers.

```cpp
void updateLinkedList(std::forward_list<int>& list)
{
    auto lastIt = list.before_begin();

    for (auto it = std::begin(list); it != std::end(list);)
    {
        if (*it)
        {
            lastIt = it++;
            int sum = *lastIt;

            while (it != std::end(list) && *it)
            {
                sum += *it;
                it++;
                list.erase_after(lastIt);
            }

            *lastIt = sum;
        }
        else
        {
            it++;
            list.erase_after(lastIt);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: for testing:

```cpp
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>

void printList(const std::forward_list<int>& list)
{
    std::cout << "{ ";
    for (auto& i : list)
    {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
}

void updateLinkedList(std::forward_list<int>& list)
{
    auto lastIt = list.before_begin();

    for (auto it = std::begin(list); it != std::end(list);)
    {
        if (*it)
        {
            lastIt = it++;
            int sum = *lastIt;

            while (it != std::end(list) && *it)
            {
                sum += *it;
                it++;
                list.erase_after(lastIt);
            }

            *lastIt = sum;
        }
        else
        {
            it++;
            list.erase_after(lastIt);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::forward_list list{
        0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0,
    };

    printList(list);
    updateLinkedList(list);
    printList(list);
}
```

[On compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9hdsoj8xj).

Answer (score 0):

In your function, the inner while loop seems to be an infinite loop if the initial value of temp!=0, since temp isn't being updated anywhere inside the loop. The node pointed to by currentNode gets updated but temp refers to the value contained by the node initially pointed to by currentNode before entering the inner while loop.